# Forms-Authentication: Can I have multiple loginUrl's?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

Is there any way I can use 2 different logUrl's with ASP.net forms authentication?  If possible, I'd like to send some users to a different login page.  I tried to add a web.config in a subdirectory (as shown below), but received this error: "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.".

I've read a number of SO posts on this & I'm thinking this is not achievable, or at least not easily achievable.  Any advice?  My site needs to have 2 login processes that are very different, which is why I'm trying to do this.

```
<!--app root-->
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="/NormalLogin/Login.aspx" />
</authentication>

<!--subdirectory-->
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="/SSOLogin/Login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Try to clean the project to remove the allowDefinition error

Comment: I tried that, but the issue is due to the <authentication> tag appearing in the subdirectory.

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, but you might get more help if you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.  For example, a single Login URL could perhaps implement two very different processes with some mechanism (e.g. cookie?) to communicate the criterion you want to use to choose between the two processes.

Comment: I'm working with a third-party SSO package that includes a http module that intercepts all requests going to the URL defined in loginURL.  With NormalLogin I was hoping to set up a different loginURL that the http module would ignore since NormalLogin's aren't SSO and therefore I don't want the SSO package to mess with them.   This doesn't seem possible though.  The alternative is to just write my own SSO integrate client to work with the SSO package.  I'm just making sure I fully understand my options before I go that route.

Answer (score 2):

What if you leave one, say `<forms loginUrl="/Login.aspx" />` and override the Page_Load method on the Login.aspx page.  There check the querystring's returnURL parameter and if it contains NormalLogin redirect them to /NormalLogin/Login.aspx otherwise to the SSOLogin/Login.aspx.